# Bind datatable to DataGridView from another Windows Form in another device?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, .net-4.0

We have one solution with two `Windows Forms Application` projects. One project has `FormInput` and the other project `FormDgv`. `FormInput` executable runs in one computer, while `FormDgv` executable runs in another computer.

Assuming I knew the IP/location of both executables, is it possible for `FormInput` to bind a DataGridView in `FormDgv`? Or maybe `FormInput` lets `FormDgv` that the DGV needs to do a rebind?

Thanks.